# Overlapping transparent shades on images in the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have certain shades (between 4 or 6, with transparency) overlap a few images on one line of a web page. [Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkEE8.jpg)
[image]

The following HTML code stacks images vertically rather than side by side, as does the transparent shades:

```
<div class = "component" style = "width: 1000px; height: 751px; background:             url(testimg.jpg)">
  <div class = "temperature" style = "background-color: #B80000; width: 500px; height: 751px; opacity: 0.6"></div>
  <div class = "temperature" style = "background-color: #680000; width: 500px; height: 751px; opacity: 0.6"></div>
</div>
<div class = "component" style = "width: 1000px; height: 751px; background: url(testimg.jpg)">
</div>
```

How can this properly be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to float these components left:

```
<div class = "component" style = "width: 1000px; height: 751px; background:             url(testimg.jpg)">
<div class = "temperature" style = "float: left; background-color: #B80000; width: 500px; height: 751px; opacity: 0.6"></div>
<div class = "temperature" style = "float: left; background-color: #680000; width: 500px; height: 751px; opacity: 0.6"></div>
</div>
<div class = "component" style = "width: 1000px; height: 751px; background: url(testimg.jpg)">
</div>
```

See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/79ny3/

Comment: That was simple enough, thanks.. Any ideas if the images exceed the horizontal width of the screen, that they won't start a new line, and instead be able to scroll horizontally?

Comment: In that case you'd probably need to remove the `width: 1000px` for the `component` class, but without seeing an example I'm not exactly sure what you'd like to achieve, try playing with the JSFiddle I posted, saving and I can get back to you.